# rails - running production mode locally = No such file to load - config/environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, production-environment

I am trying to run locally in production mode with:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

But I get:

```
/home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/li
b/active_support/dependencies.rb:306:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file
 to load -- /home/durrantm/Dropnot/webs/rails_apps/linker/app/assets/../con
fig/environment (LoadError)
```

I can create a brand new rails `3.1.8` app and do `RAILS_ENV=production rails server` and I don't get this problem.

I can also do `rails s` and that runs the server fine in development mode without error.

I can also do `RAILS_ENV=development rails s` and that runs the server fine in development mode without error.

fwiw, my app was originally a rails `2.3` app so perhaps I am missing something that's been added or changed in rails ?

I do have the `config` directory with an `environment.rb` file.  Perhaps the way it's being referenced is wrong somehow?

I added `config.assets.enabled = true` to `config/application.rb` but it didn't help (didn't expect it to as that is asset compilation, but it was a difference I found!).

Full Trace:

```
durrantm@Castle2012:~/Dropnot/webs/rails_apps/linker/config/environments (v3.1.8_with_assets)
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.8 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:306:in `rescue in depend_on': No such file to load -- /home/durrantm/Dropnot/webs/rails_apps/linker/app/assets/../config/environment (LoadError)
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:301:in `depend_on'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `require_dependency'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:417:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `each'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `block in eager_load!'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `each'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `eager_load!'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /home/durrantm/Dropnot/webs/rails_apps/linker/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
        from /home/durrantm/Dropnot/webs/rails_apps/linker/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
        from /home/durrantm/Dropnot/webs/rails_apps/linker/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from /home/durrantm/Dropnot/webs/rails_apps/linker/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@linker/gems/railties-3.1.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Something is weird. It is looking for the `config/` directory inside the `app/` directory. It should not be looking there.

Comment: yeah, that's the weird part for sure...

Comment: What could cause that?  This is an app I've had running well for a few years and upgraded thru a few rails versions and havne't run into anything like this.  I'm current going thru the `config/` directory (right now I'm going thru `initializers/` but not seeing anything yet...

Comment: Are you attempting to upgrade from 2 to 3 right now? Or have you had it working on 3?

Comment: I have it working on rails 3.1.8 ok but without asset compilation.  I'm trying to now make it work with asset compilation.  The app itself started at about rails 2.3.8 originally.

Comment: btw The live app is here: http://www.railslinks.com/

Answer (score 3):

Changed a few things.  One of the main ones were to enable static assets locally in `config/environments/production.rb` when trying to run it locally (only) and revert that before pushing to a production web server.  I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

seems like your old `assets` directory lived in other place (maybe in `public`) and now it is in `app/assets`, but it doesn't know about it and some files try to load `environment.rb`. just double check assets dir.

Comment: Yes, assets were previously just in `public/`.  I've moved them into /app/assets/  I tried doing a `rake assets:precompile` but it didn't create the `/public` structure as I expected..

Comment: Ah, adding the public directory was important.  Once I added that directory, `rake assets:precompile` was _then_ able to copy the assets to the `public/assets` directory.  Unfortunately this *still* gives the `No such file to load -- /home/durrantm/Dropnot/webs/rails_apps/linker/app/assets/../config/environment (LoadError)` msg when I do `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`.  grrrr!

Comment: btw "double check assets dir", sure, and... ?

Comment: you should debug to see which dependencies try to load `config/environment`)

Comment: How to debug?  I tried `RAILS_ENV=production rails s --debug but it didn't seem to enter debug mode.  Also how to set a breakpoint?  Seems like rails startup will involve thousands of lines of code that I'm not sure I'll be able to handle.

Comment: Which files try to load `environment.rb` normally?

Comment: ok, debugging it's another topic but you could `debugger` and good start it's `run_initializers` point.

Comment: Anyway, are you sure that you using proper version `sprokets` for example, do you run your commands using bundler? `bundle exec rails s`